# Разархивировать многотомный архив rar средствами C#

Tags: c#, архивация

Требуется программно разархивировать многотомник rar

Comment: Зачем это делать руками, если можно скачать тот же 7zip и запускать его с параметрами, чтобы он сам распаковывал что надо и куда надо?

Comment: https://github.com/p3root/sharpcompress

Comment: @tym32167 Ага. И при запуске: "Дорогой пользователь! Моя программа не умеет самостоятельно распаковывать нужные архивы, так что скачайте, пожалуйста, 7zip". Да и в любом случае - это костыль

Comment: @PrimusSingularis спасибо. Сейчас ознакомлюсь

Comment: @Kir_Antipov это зависит от требований, конечно. Мне надо было поддерживать кучу форматов архива, потому я юзал такой костыль и не заморачивался

Comment: Идём на nuget, вбиваем в поиск [rar](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=rar), выбираем понравившийся пакет.